# Shift+Enter in Textarea using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code shows how to use a directive to submit a form by hitting 'enter' while in a textarea. However, I would like to be able to shift+enter and go to the next line and submit the result as it is. Whenever the submission is made, it shows up in the same line. How do I submit and show the submitted text in the next line as the user intends.

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <textarea ng-model="foo" enter-submit="submit()"></textarea><br/>
  Last submitted text: {{ lastSubmitted }}<br/>
</div>
```

The AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.foo = ""
  $scope.lastSubmitted = ""

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.lastSubmitted = $scope.foo; 
  }
}

app.directive('enterSubmit', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
          var code = event.keyCode || event.which;

          if (code === 13) {
            if (!event.shiftKey) {
              event.preventDefault();
              scope.$apply(attrs.enterSubmit);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to convert `\n\r` into `<br/>` then use `ng-bind-html` to sanitize the string.

Here is a [code example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jB9TWJypceCFxmc2OcmO)

You will also have to include the angularjs sanitize js file:
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-sanitize.js"></script>`